# Childadded retrieves one key

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some problems when I add a new node to the Firebase Realtime Database. I get some data back when I add a child, but the problem is that I retrieve the key and 1 value, but there are 2 values total.

I have the following structure:

```
-- groups 
    -- id
      -- members
        -- id
          --device_name
          --device_type
```

I observe the members child. And I want to retrieve the id and underlaying elements (device_name, device_type) when that child is added.

I do that with this code:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("groups").child(roomObject.getAutoChildId()).child("members");
    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot.debugDescription)
})
```

But now the problem. snapshot.debugDescription returns not all the values in that snapshot. Example:

```
Snap (ooDpijaPrKgcBA70LUXYbpohvi42) {
    "device_name" = test;
}
```

The device_type key is not there, and I don't know why. I need this:

```
Snap (ooDpijaPrKgcBA70LUXYbpohvi42) {
    "device_name" = test;
    "device_type" = test;
}
```

Added the structure:

[image]

Comment: Can you show the screenshot of you firebase database?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 I have added the screenshot.

Comment: if you add print(snapshot) only then what is the output?

Comment: I think that I know what's going wrong, I insert device_name and device_type one by one. I think it has to do with timing. So I'm going to try to do it in bulk.

Comment: please do share your solution, if you find it , thanks

Comment: I have found and added the solution, Thanks for your help @3stud1ant3

Answer (score 2):

I have found what was going wrong. It has nothing to do with the .childAdded, that part is working fine.

It goes wrong at the insert. What I did was the following:

```
let insertRef = reference.child("groups").child(roomKey).child("members").child(roomCodeArray[1])   
    insertRef.child("device_name").setValue(roomCodeArray[2])
    insertRef.child("device_type").setValue(roomCodeArray[3])
```

But firebase is so freakin fast that when device_name is inserted, the other device retrieves the onchildChanged event. The device type is not added at that moment.

My solution:

```
let childInsert = [
                   "device_name" : roomCodeArray[2],
                   "device_type" : roomCodeArray[3]
                  ]

insertRef.setValue(childInsert)
```

Insert the values at the same time. And then it works like magic.